# Do I need an Mac to post an app to the app store?

Tags: iphone

Do I need to a Mac computer to post an app to the app store? Can I post an app using my PC?

Comment: Please it is a Mac, not MAC. They are different things. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the application loader, or the organizer in Xcode, both are Mac OS applications.

So yes, you will need a Mac to upload the binary.

Answer (score -1):

No you don't.  You need to create the app on a Mac and zip it up, but you upload your app via iTunes Connect, which is accessed via a web browser.

edit:  My answer is apparently obsolete.  Apparently you now *do* need to use a Mac.

Comment: when was the last time you did this? A year ago? Must be more if I remember correctly.

Comment: you can't upload to the app store with a browser. You must use application loader. I believe they made this change in September or so.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Wrong answers and the commentary associated with them generally add support to the correct answer.  Any honest attempt to contribute usefully to the answer should be recorded and retained for future reference.